# Get array_agg(id) arrays for each k records in table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to query a snowflake table such that all of its records would be batched into rows containing id arrays of, at most, k elements.
For instance, if `k=2`, and the table contained records with ids `1,2,3,4,5`, I'd like to issue a query that could return `[1,2]`, `[3,4]`, `[5]` (the actual batching criteria would be unimportant). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need a pseudo-column based on which we can do grouping to create these sets.
Using row_number() and do `DIV` to create groups as per value of `k`.

Few examples given below -

```
with cte(col1) as (
    select * from values
    (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)
)
,cte_1 as (
    select ceil(row_number() over (order by null)/3) rn, 
       col1 
    from cte
)
select array_agg(col1) agg_output 
from cte_1 
group by rn order by rn;
```

| AGG_OUTPUT |
| --- |
| [ 1, 2, 3 ] |
| [ 4, 5, 6 ] |
| [ 7, 8, 9 ] |

Answer (score 2):

I like Pankaj's answer, I and thought I could get rid of the second CTE (without making it a sub-select) but in the end it is needed for scoping reasons.

I did flip to using a variable to control the bucketing. And I added two ORDER BY's firstly to the bucket, I used the values in question, so it can be seen how to not randomly allocate the values into buckets. And secondly a WITHIN GROUP on the array so the values are always "in order" both perhaps not required. But also not stated as not required. But if the answers are always want this way, the ORDER BY are required.

```
set width = 4;

with table_of_numbers(val) as (
    -- just a CTE to make 14 numbers
    select 
        row_number() over(order by null)
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 14))
), pre_cond as(
    select *,
        ceil(row_number() over (order by val)/$width) as rn
    from table_of_numbers
)
select 
    array_agg(val)within group(order by val) agg_output 
from pre_cond 
group by rn order by rn;
```

gives:

| AGG_OUTPUT |
| --- |
| [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] |
| [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ] |
| [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ] |
| [ 13, 14 ] |

The points to note on the bucketing is ROW_NUMBER starts at 1 thus the Nth values will be a natural interval, thus CEIL is needed to push the prio N-1 partials into the same bucket. As there is not integer only division (with natural floor) subtracting 1 form ROW_NUMBER cannot be leveraged for a simpler logic.

Answer (score 1):

This likely won't outperform Pankaj' answer, but it avoids a subquery. Maybe `array_slice` reads more self-documenting. Add `within group (order by..)` to `array_agg` if ordering matters

```
set K=3;

select array_slice(array_agg(col) over (),
                   sum($K) over (order by col) - $K,  
                   sum($K) over (order by col)) as array_part
from cte
qualify array_size(array_part) > 0
```